# Calculating confidence intervals for two samples

Tags: r, confidence-interval, t-test

Let's say I have two samples and I want to calculate confidence intervals for the means of each sample.

```
x = rnorm(10)
y = rnorm(10)
```

Using the t.test command I'm able to get the following output.

```
> t.test(x, y)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x and y
t = -0.0104, df = 17.17, p-value = 0.9918
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.077822  1.067245
sample estimates:
 mean of x  mean of y 
-0.2235438 -0.2182557
```

However, what if I want the 95% confidence intervals for each sample. Is that a manual calculation I have to do. I want to generate confidence intervals for each sample so that I can compare the two in regards to whether I should reject the null hypothesis.

Basically, I want to mimic [this](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi22/STATS/PAPER270.PDF) in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question leave some considerable doubt about what, exactly, *this* in 'mimic this' consists of. You should be more explicit.

Do you want one sample confidence intervals for the means?

Then `t.test` can do it easily, by doing it one sample at a time.

```
t.test(x,conf.int=TRUE)
t.test(y,conf.int=TRUE)
```

You can even extract the confidence interval part of the output and if you want, assign it to a variable:

```
 t.test(y,conf.int=TRUE)$conf.int
```

(Or do you want to know how to produce a particular display? That's easy enough, once the values are calculated.)